# A generic set operations class i.e. intersection, union, minus etc

Tags: c++, c, set-operations

I want to write a C++ class that offers set operations that work on vectors of strings and vectors of my own data type.  Are there any easy ways of doing this rather than writing a different function for each data type?  So far I have written operations for string vectors.  Below shows an example of my set union:

```
vector<string> SetOperations::set_union(vector<string> set1,
                                        vector<string> set2) {
    for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < set1.size(); i++) {
        set1.push_back(set2.at(i));
    }
    return set1;
}
```

So I want the same thing again but where `string` is say `my_data_type` which is a struct of various members.  Let's say it looks like this:

```
struct my_data_type {
    int label;
    vector<string> x;
    vector<string> y;
    string str;
};
```

A function for each data type would also not be as simple as my `set_union(...)` function because surely I would need to test for equality on each member of `my_data_type` in the case of set intersection?

Also, I'm quite new to C++ so any comments on my existing function would be appreciated too.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are already such algorithms (union, intersection, sorting, ...): http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/

Your elements simply need to meet the requirements for STL container elements (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb385469.aspx):

> All reference types that are inserted
>   into STL/CLR containers must have, at
>   a minimum, the following elements:
>
> A public copy constructor.
>
> A public assignment operator.
>
> A public destructor.
>
> Furthermore, associative containers
>   such as set and map must have a public
>   comparison operator defined, which is
>   operator< by default. Some operations
>   on containers might also require a
>   public default constructor and a
>   public equivalence operator to be
>   defined.
>
> Like reference types, value types and
>   handles to reference types that are to
>   be inserted into an associative
>   container must have a comparison
>   operator such as operator< defined.
>   The requirements for a public copy
>   constructor, public assignment
>   operator, and a public destructor do
>   not exist for value types or handles
>   to reference types.

You can find information about operator overloading (to be implemented in your custom class) on that WikiBook: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Operators/Operator_Overloading

Answer (score 6):

Some of these already exist and are in the algorithm header:

- set_union
- set_difference
- set_intersection
- set_symmetric_difference

These all support a comparator function so that you could do it to all your own data types. Or as posted in the other reply make your Containers comply to the STL requirements.

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/