# set_union on arbitrary structs - where have I gone wrong?

Tags: c++, algorithm, struct

This is a continuation of my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294036/using-the-algorithm-library-on-arbitrary-data-types) that told me what to do nicely but implementing it didn't work :S.  All I want is set_union (and the other set operations) in the C++ algorithm class to work on my structs.  Here's what I have so far.

My struct:

```
struct player {
    int lbl;
    int lbl1;

    bool operator<(const player &t) const {
        return (lbl < t.lbl && lbl1 < t.lbl);
    }
};
```

which defines the < operator on my struct i.e. one player is 'smaller' than another player if both of its labels (integers) are smaller than the other player's labels.

Then to perform the set_union I do this:

```
    player p1;
    p1.lbl = 1;
    p1.lbl1 = 3;

    player p2;
    p2.lbl = 3;
    p2.lbl1 = 5;

    player p3;
    p3.lbl = 2;
    p3.lbl1 = 8;

    player p4;
    p4.lbl = 1;
    p4.lbl1 = 7;

    vector<player> v1;
    vector<player> v2;
    v1.push_back(p2);
    v1.push_back(p1);
    v2.push_back(p3);
    v2.push_back(p4);

    sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());

    vector<player> v;
    set_union(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(),
              back_inserter(v));

    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        cout << v.at(i).lbl << ", " << v.at(i).lbl1 << endl;
    }
```

which prints:

```
1, 3
3, 5
```

when it should have printed

```
1, 3
3, 5
2, 8
1, 7
```

because it's set union.  I have probably gone wrong in the struct definition somewhere?  The same set_union works on vectors of both strings and integers so it's probably my player struct?

Thank you.

**additional code**

My actual struct code is below (with corrections suggested by Nawaz).  I originally posted a simplified version but I possibly need to post all of it:

```
struct player {
    int i;
    int lbl;
    int lbl1;
    argument argu;
    string player_name;

    player(string player_name);

    bool operator<(const player &t) const {
        if ( lbl != t.lbl )
            return lbl < t.lbl;
        return lbl1 < t.lbl1;
    }

};
```

Comment: Don't tag questions as C++ and C... they're two different languages and are much easier to use when you pick one or the other (though you *can* code for both, in theory).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should implement [Strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering), because **associative containers** such as `std::set`, `std::multiset`, `std::map`, `std::multimap`  require that the ordering of elements must be  [`Strict Weak Ordering`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering). And in your case, `set_union` operates on the data according to the `std::set` rules, which requires *strict weak ordering* but your comparison function doesn't implement it. Hence the problem!

Also note what [the documentation of std::set_union](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_union/) at cplusplus says,

> Comparison function object that, taking two values of the same type than those contained in the range, returns true if the first argument goes before the second argument in the specific **strict weak ordering** it defines, and false otherwise.

So, your comparison function should be like this:

```
struct player {
    int lbl;
    int lbl1;

    bool operator<(const player &t) const 
    {
        if ( lbl != t.lbl )
               return lbl < t.lbl;
        return lbl1 < t.lbl1;
    }
};
```

This will give correct output. See this online demo:

http://www.ideone.com/d4Kob

Comment: @Nawaz and also, why is strict weak ordering needed?  Should I have heard of it before?

Comment: @Nawaz Let me replace my first comment with one that makes more sense: "Thank you :). Mine still doesn't work though! Does it matter that in my actual code, I also have a vector of strings and a string as well as the two labels in the struct? I didn't include them in the post because they're not used for comparing players. Any ideas? Thanks again."

Comment: @vivid-colours: I didn't understand  your question? What implementation still doesn't work? Did you implement strict weak ordering?

Comment: @Nawaz: I've added my full struct code to the post with your suggested changes.  It still produces the incorrect output but maybe some of the other members are breaking it?  Not sure.  The argument type in the struct is just another struct.  Any ideas? :S

Comment: @vivid-colours: What output do you get now?

Comment: Same as before:
1, 3 and 
3, 5

Comment: @vivid-colours: Have you posted the complete rest of the post?

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes, see the bottom of the post in the bold text :).  Thank you!

Comment: @vivid-colours: Post the complete code here at http://www.ideone.com and run it. I want to see the output myself, and want to see how exactly you've implemented it.

Comment: @Nawaz: Thanks for all the help - SOLVED!  I deleted the .o files that the compile created, rebuilt and it worked.  It must have been using an old copy of the head file containing the struct definition - very weird.  Thank you.